# why java decompiler does not show the correct code with lambdas?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have this simple kotlin class:

```
class MyClass {

    private val x: Int = 10
    val m: (Int) -> Int = { a: Int ->
        a*a + a
    }
}
```

and I used the IntelliJ decompiler and this is the java code:

```
public final class MyClass {
    private final int x = 10;
    @NotNull
    private final Function1 m;

    @NotNull
    public final Function1 getM() {
        return this.m;
    }

    public MyClass() {
        this.m = (Function1)null.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

as you can see there is no sign of what's placed in the lambda argument `m` which is `a*a + a` in the java code and it always returns a `null` value for `m`. however, there exists a bytecode for that code:

```
public final invoke(I)I
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
    // annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
   L0
    LINENUMBER 7 L0
    ILOAD 1
    ILOAD 1
    IMUL
    ILOAD 1
    IADD
   L1
    IRETURN
   L2
```

I guess this is a problem with decompiler right? if so what decompiler should I use?

Comment: Decompilation is not a perfect process.

Comment: I do not know what `intellij` is using, but what does `javap` say in this case?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I can see that. I'm asking for a better decompiler if anyone knows any